# Should I enable the ATI Proprietary Driver?

Tags: graphics, ati

Have the ATI Drivers improved any? Are they any better than the default open source driver? Are they worth enabling?

Comment: The answer is hardware dependent. Not all ATI are supported equally by both drivers. Which graphic card do you have?.

Comment: Also, please define "better" and what you think would make it worth enabling

Comment: Not sure "better" is debatable. 2D/3D improved performance, power requirements, etc can all be addressed by an answer.

Comment: @Oli - yes, but knowing which of those is the most important will help people answer the question

Comment: It's built into my HP Pavilion dv6, does that help any? and will it mess up the boot logo like the Nvidia drivers? if so, is there a fix to that?

Answer (score 6):

> Have the ATI Drivers improved any?

- Yes, quite a bit. But not enough.

> Are they any better than the default
>   open source driver?

- They offer better performance, power management. But they also contain more errors and are less likely to be improved in short intervals of time.

> Are they worth enabling?

- If you're unhappy with graphics performance, cetrainly. If you are quite happy with the current situation, you wouldn't gain anything from enabling them. But you would potentially expose yourself to a few new bugs and errors.

They have improved a lot. And there is not big disadvantage to enabling them. But if you are happy without them, save yourself some *potential* trouble.

Comment: There's really no reason not to try, though. Enable them, if you get some annoying bug just disable them.